# HTTP POST JSON Method

Tags: iphone, json, http, post

Hi I need help in making a HTTP POST connection to a web service. I am totally clueless on how to do it.

I only had experienced in making a NSURLConnection whereby I pass the required input parameters as part of the URL. Now it seems different as I am only provided a website and the request JSON body.

```
{
"lastmodified":"String content",
"passengerId":9223372036854775807,
"password":"String content",
"userId":"String content"
}
```

Could anyone shed some light on this? Say the website is www.myURL/operations/AddItem.com

EDIT - What am I doing wrong here?

```
NSError *theError = nil;
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"userId", @"password", nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:userNameTextField.text, passwordTextField.text, nil];
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

NSString *myJSONString =[jsonDictionary JSONRepresentation];
NSData *myJSONData =[myJSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"myJSONString :%@", myJSONString); 
NSLog(@"myJSONData :%@", myJSONData); 

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://153.20.32.74/11AprP306/passenger/item"]];
[request setHTTPBody:myJSONData]; 
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&theResponse error:&theError];   
NSLog(@"response : %@", theResponse);
NSLog(@"error : %@", theError);
NSLog(@"data : %@", data);
NSMutableString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"string: %@", string);
NSDictionary *jsonDictionaryResponse = [string JSONValue];
NSLog(@"dic: %@", jsonDictionaryResponse);
[string release];
[theResponse release];
```

I am reading `string: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1 transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Request Error</title>
    <style>BODY {..... 'The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'.`

Is it because I have short passed some values(lastmodified & passengerId)? I have no idea why do they need these 2 parameters as this request is only creating a new account.

Comment: [`ASIHTTPRequest`](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest). Use the `appendPostData:` or `appendPostDataFromFile:` methods to add the JSON dict.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `ASIHTTPRequest` as @darvids0n suggests, or you could also do it using the standard iOS `NSMutableURLRequest` method as follows:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:myURL]; // Assumes you have created an NSURL * in "myURL"
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:myJSONData]; // Assumes you have created an NSData * for your JSON
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
```

However you choose to do it, you will need to convert your Objective-C object(s) into a JSON string and then convert that into an NSData. Here is an example of how to do both those steps at once using the [SBJSON](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) framework.

```
SBJsonWriter *writer = [[SBJsonWriter alloc] init];
NSData *myJSONData = [writer dataWithObject:myDataDictionary];
```

The above converts the dictionary into a JSON string and then converts that string into an NSData using UTF8 encoding of the string. If you want a different encoding you will have to break use `[writer stringWithObject:myDataDictionary]` and encode it yourself.

Comment: So I need to create a NSDictionary with 4 objects(lastmodified, passengerID,...) and convert them to NSData and finally use a json parser to convert it to JSON data?

Comment: Typically you will place your object into a dictionary, then convert that dictionary into a JSON string using a framework such as SBJSON (http://stig.github.com/json-framework/). The SBJSONStreamWriter class is one that can convert an NSDictionary to a stream of bytes. You can set yourself as a delegate to receive those bytes and append them into an NSData object. Once you have the NSData you can add it to the HTTP POST request.

Comment: I came across some examples whereby they setHTTPBody as a JSONString. Hmm?

Comment: The setHTTPBody requires an NSData object as an input parameter. However you get the data values converted into JSON, you will need that JSON to then be converted into an NSData. It's pretty easy to convert from a JSON string to an NSData if that's what you have available. SBJSON is just one framework for parsing/generating JSON. It is not the only way to do  it though.

Comment: Could you take a look at my edited answer and advise what is the method to call to convert the JSONString to JSONData? Please advise if some of the statements seems incorrect.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to parse an existing JSON string using SBJSONParser: What you really want is to go the other way and write a JSON string from your dictionary object. I'll update my solution to try and show how to do that easily

Comment: why am I getting an error of `-JSONValue failed. Error is: Illegal start of token [<]`?

Comment: Update your code in the original post so that it is current. Can't tell what's going on based on what's currently posted

Comment: It's updated now. I am reading rubbish for my string though, is that the reason why the conversion failed? `string: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> ....` One part actually says `The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'`

Comment: It looks like your service requires you (the client) to tell it the format of what you are sending. Because you don't tell it, it assumes a default of "Raw". You'll seed to figure out how your service expects that information to be specified. In many cases, it depends on an HTTP content-type header. I'll update my example to include how to set that for a JSON content type. If that doesn't do it, your service may require some kind of custom header or URL parameter that you'll have to research.